# Configuring Squid to cache media streams

Tags: linux, networking

Does anyone know how to configure Squid to cache streaming media, such as iPlayer and YouTube?
I have a 40+ user student network, and am seeing a lot of hits to the same pages, so it would be great (and easier on our connection!) if these sort of things could be cached so they only need to load once.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Interesting technical question, but I am wondering why you allow access to these sites on your network?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like it can be done, but apparently it's not easy.  They also said this:

> Be advised this demonstrated
>   configuration has a mixed success
>   rate, it works for some but others
>   have reported it strangely not working
>   at all.

Have a look at [this article](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples/DynamicContent/YouTube) on their wiki.

Comment: All I can say is worked for me whan I tested it a while back.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest trying out [Videocache](http://cachevideos.com/), it is written especially to cache youtube and other streaming video sites with Squid. I used it several versions ago and it seemed promising. Also the feature that it allows the admin to browse the videos afterwards was very handy (I managed to save several videos that were removed from Youtube).